# Connect Liferay 6.1.1 to LDAP Zimbra from Virtualbox

Tags: ldap, openldap, zimbra, liferay

I want to connect liferay to zimbra in Virtual Box and I need to fill this form :

![Capture of liferay try to connect to ldap in VB]

[image]

I got the url and password from the output of this command :

```
zimbra@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu$ zmlocalconfig -s zimbra_ldap_password ldap_master_url
zimbra_ldap_password = uGNs5PjD
ldap_master_url = ldap://ubuntu.formation.com:389
```

please I want to know if the other information are alright ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `base DN` should be the name of the domain that your zimbra server is responsible for, but in distinguishedName syntax. That is, if your domain were `example.com`, the Base DN would be `dc=example,dc=com`. If your domain is `sub.example.com`, then your base DN would be `dc=sub,dc=example,dc=com`. Your domain name may not be the same as your server name, depending on your setup.

Also, your `principal` is likely incorrect. The value of `zimbra_ldap_userdn` is probably what you should use, by default it's `uid=zimbra,cn=admins,cn=zimbra`, which is likely why you can't connect now. You could also use/create another appropriate DN within zimbra's LDAP, but I'm not sure how well that would be handled by upgrades (more the relevant ACLs, rather than the dn itself).

```
$ zmlocalconfig zimbra_ldap_userdn
zimbra_ldap_userdn = uid=zimbra,cn=admins,cn=zimbra
```

Comment: Ok thanks ill put in "Base DN" and please what should I do about "Principal" and "credentials" I got some of the information from "/opt/zimbra/data/ldap/ldap.bak" but it's not workin at all and I need to get it done as soon as possible thank you

Comment: @SoukaProgrammer I think you've misunderstood. I've edited in an attempt to clarify.